# How to change the structure of a model in PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to build a stacked auto encoder or recursive network. These are necessary to build a *dynamic* neural network, which can change its structure in each iteration.

For example, I first train

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784,500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500,784)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x
```

next, I want to train using previous fc1 and fc2

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784,500)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(500,10)        
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(10,500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500,784)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x
```

How can I build these networks in single model?

Comment: Can you elaborate and be more precise? What is it exactly that you want? Create new layers on the fly for instance? You could do this with a simple for loop within the forward method that would depend on the input `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an argument to your forward function, which can switch between the two possibilities you want:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784,500)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(500,10)        
    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(10,500)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500,784)

def forward(self, x, n_layers=2):
    if 2 == n_layers:
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x
    elif 4 == n_layers:
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x
    else:
        raise Exception("Not implemented")
```

Comment: These will leave the NN with only two (however many one programmed) options. I think, the question was related to automated neural architecture search. If one knows how to allow an NN add nodes and layers without such fixed and explicit declarations, please add to these=) Very much interested to see how to implement it in PyTorch.